# Total number of $4$-digit numbers such that the sum of digits is odd is? (Repetition Allowed)

Tags: combinatorics

> Total number of $4$-digit numbers such that the sum of digits is odd is?

It can happen if there are exactly one odd digit or exactly one even digit.But I'm getting too many cases like when there are two zeroes or one zero or when the are two like numbers.I'm getting confused...

What would be the best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count up the total number of 4 digit numbers. If you don't allow leading zeros, it is the range $[1000,9999]$  Having chosen the first three digits, you have to have the fourth digit of a specified parity.  As half the fourth digits are the right  parity, half of all four digit numbers have an odd digit sum.

Comment: OMG...I never thought of that...:-P I was so engrossed with dividing the situation into different cases :-P Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

$P_1$ = probability that the first digit adds to odd = 5/9. (Can't have leading zero).

$P_n$ = probability that the first $n > 1$ digits add to odd = $P_{n-1}*P($ n-th digit is even$) + (1 - P_{n-1})*P($ n-th digit is odd$) = P_{n-1}*1/2 + (1-P_{n-1})*1/2 = (P_{n-1} + 1 - P_{n-1})1/2 = 1/2$

Basically so long as at least one digit isn't restricted, then it doesn't matter what the rest of the digits add to or what the probability  of the rest of the digits adding to even or odd are.  *Half* the options the the unrestricted digit will keep the parity, and *half* will change the parity.  So the probability is always 1/2.